# Where is the system wide PATH shell variable set in OS X?

Tags: macos, unix

I'd like to set the `PATH` shell variable for all users, but could not find where it is defined.

Having no `export PATH` in my `.bash_profile`, I have this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Where is this the `PATH` shell variable defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On a shell level, the `PATH` variable is set in `/etc/profile` by calling `/usr/libexec/path_helper`. To add your own paths, you can add files with a path in it to `/etc/paths.d/`:

```bash
$ ls -l /etc/paths.d
total 8
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  13 Jul 22 07:02 50-X11
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  12 Aug 13 14:12 TeX
$ cat /etc/paths.d/TeX 
/Library/TeX/texbin
```

That's the safer way than editing `/etc/profile`, `/etc/paths` or any other system-provided file which may get overwritten with the next OSX upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly more complete list of places where `PATH` might be (re)defined on macOS:

1. `/etc/paths`
2. entries under `/etc/paths.d`
3. - <kbd>bash:</kbd> `/etc/profile` `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` `~/.bashrc`
   - <kbd>zsh:</kbd> `~/.zshenv` `/etc/zprofile` `/etc/zshrc` `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` `~/.zshrc` `~/.zprofile`

`/usr/libexec/path_helper` collects entries from `/etc/paths`, `/etc/paths.d`, and then the shell — `bash`, `zsh`, etc — applies on top of that its own customizations.

Keep in mind that each of the files in the chain might include more files, so watch closely for lines that start with `. some-file` or `source some-file`. For example, you might find something like `source ~/.bash_profile` in your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: `path_helper` only reads `/etc/paths` and the files in `/etc/paths.d`, not the shell-specific startup files.

Comment: @nohillside: running `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` on ventura 13.5 includes all the extra `PATH` additions from `~/.zshrc`

Comment: Not according to [`path_helper.c`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/e256b9a97f9bbd751305b7af36cf751668fbb849/path_helper/path_helper.c), see line [243](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/shell_cmds/blob/e256b9a97f9bbd751305b7af36cf751668fbb849/path_helper/path_helper.c#L243). Try `PATH= /usr/libexec/path_helper -s` to start with an empty path, and just see the things `path_helper` adds :-)

Comment: indeed, that matches with `man path_helper`; answer updated, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you really wanted to OVERWRITE the path, you could just set the new one in /etc/launchd.conf.  There is a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/16355/how-to-set-global-path-on-os-x/277034#277034).