# Where do I find what's all affecting my $PATH?

Tags: command-line, bash, path

When I echo `$PATH` I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/arukaj/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/
```

However, I have no idea where this stuff is coming from.

When I try `cat ~/.bashrc`, I get `PS1='\u@\h:\w\$ '` for my shell formatting.

If I try `cat ~/.bash_profile`, I get:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.5
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then 
    source ~/.bashrc 
fi
```

Is the `PATH` environmental variable being constructed before `.bash_profile` is read? It looks like it's appending Python onto the front of the current `PATH` and then exporting itself as `PATH` again, although I don't know why the syntax is `${PATH}` here as opposed to `$PATH`.

Anyhow, I don't know where the Android and XAMPP stuff is coming from. How do I know where to look?

Comment: Check /etc/paths and /etc/path.d.

Comment: /etc/paths just has 

```/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin```

other path is empty

Comment: Look over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9832770/where-is-the-default-terminal-path-located-on-mac

Comment: @ComicSans Basically the same answer as above

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is the system wide PATH shell variable set in OS X?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/33232/where-is-the-system-wide-path-shell-variable-set-in-os-x)

Comment: You did not specify what kind of bash you are executing (interactive vs. non-interactive, login vs. non-login). Start exactly the same kind of bash again, but also specifying the -x option. Then check the output to see where PATH changes.